# How to square the second largest number in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, math

I'm trying to find the 2nd largest number in an array, and square this number.

`arr = [1,8,6,2,5,4,8,3,7]` should return 49 (7 squared)

`arr = [1,1]` should return 1 (1 squared)

I've tried the code below and it works on the first array and return 49, but on the second array with [1,1] it returns NaN.

The problem is with the secondLargest variable--it returns undefined on the console.log. It may be because I'm using set, but I don't understand why it's not just returning 1 instead of undefined.

```
var maxArea = function(height) {

    let secondLargest = Array.from([...new Set(height)]).sort((a,b) => b-a)[1]
    console.log(secondLargest);
    
    return Math.pow(secondLargest, 2);
};
```

Comment: Well the set will have an element for `1`, and... that's pretty much it. Yet after sorting you want to get a second element.

Comment: @ASDFGerte Thank you, that makes sense as to why it's returning undefined

Answer (score 2):

`Set` eliminates duplicates, so the array `[1, 1]` gets turned into `[1]`. There is no second element, so you get undefined when trying to access index `1`. Since this is not what you want, sort the array directly without creating a `Set`, or take the first element when there is no second element.

```js
function maxArea(height) {
  const sorted = [...new Set(height)].sort((a,b) => b-a);
  return (sorted[1] ?? sorted[0]) ** 2;
}
console.log(maxArea([1, 1]));
console.log(maxArea([1,8,6,2,5,4,8,3,7]));
```